# Xcode project shows with error after updating to Xcode to 6.3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

I had a project in xcode (Swift). before everything was perfect. I only entered to the AppStore and i updated the Xcode. After that i updated the Xcode to the version 6.3.1, my project shows with many errors  like shows in the picture below, every time that i want to run it. How can it resolve it please ??

[image]

Answer (score 6):

That's normal unfortunately. Xcode 6.3 comes with Swift 1.2 what usually breaks your code done with previous swift versions.

Xcode has a tool to automatically migrate to 1.2. If that doesn't work, you'll need to address those errors one by one (or at least those that automatic migration didn't fix).

To migrate, click the Edit menu, then choose Convert > To latest swift syntax.

Comment: i don't see Swift 1.2, i only see 1) To latest swift syntax. 2) To XCText. 3) To modern Objetif C Syntax. 4) To Objetive -c ARC. Which one must i choose please?

Comment: @JoelFelixSTJOY: use `To latest swift syntax`

Comment: It's generating preview. I'm waiting for.

Comment: @Joel Felix ST JOY: Double check that you migrated property. if migration doesn't work, you'll need to fix them manually. Usually they are not very hard to fix.

Comment: if you have a backup somewhere dump xcode 6.3 go back to 6.2. migrating hoses your code. if you've used a 3rd party lib that hasn't updates you're in for painfull modifications. im in middle of big project and found out the hard way. the migrator sucks and gives wrong errors and wouldn't compile code that ran.o

Comment: @GAlexander how can i go to back to 6.2?

Comment: I always archive versions but if you don't, you might have to pay Apple $99 and get a developer account.  You can get previous Xcode there. `https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode`  or google there is probably a copy somewhere.

Comment: @GAlexander the problem that before the project worked perfectly, i just updated it, that why i have all these errors

Comment: yes, sounds familiar. revert back to 6.2 unless you want to bug hunt.  sometimes the bugs are easy `as` to `as?` other times painful to track down.